# Обрезать текст до первого слеша с конца PHP

Tags: php, строки

Допустим есть такой текст:

```
C:\AppServ\www\modules\test.php
```

Мне нужно оставить test.php
Как это сделать на php?

Comment: [path_info($path,PATHINFO_FILENAME)](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам надо по экзотически то вот:

```
<?php $str = 'C:\AppServ\www\modules\test.php';
$str = explode('\', $str);
echo $str[count($str-1)];
?>
```

Это способ не является лучшим)

Comment: этот отбросил потому что уж больно топорный) может что-то по проще есть)?

Comment: лучше уж так `echo array_pop(explode('\', $str));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = 'C:\AppServ\www\modules\test.php';
    strrchr($str, chr(92));
?>
```